# TypeError: knapSack() missing 3 required positional arguments

Tags: python, tkinter

I just start learning tkinter python for knapsack program. When I try to calculate, it doesn't do anything. And I am getting this error:

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1921, in **call**
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: knapSack() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'W', 'wt', and 'val'

My code looks like this

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("0/1 Knapsack")

canvas = tk.Canvas(window, height=1000, width=1000, bg = "#ADD8E6")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(window, bg="white")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8,relx=0.1,rely=0.1)


def on_submit():
    num_entries = int(num_entries_entry.get())
    for i in range(num_entries):
        Title_label = tk.Label(frame, text = "Items information")
        Title_label.grid(row=5, column=1)
        Title_label.config(font=("Arial", 18))
        entry = tk.Entry(frame)
        entry_label = tk.Label(frame, text = " Weight of items : " )
        entry_label.grid(row=6,column=0)
        entry.grid(row=7+i, column=0)
        entry2 = tk.Entry(frame)
        entry2_label = tk.Label(frame, text = " Value of each items")
        entry2_label.grid(row=6, column=1)
        entry2.grid(row=7+i, column=1)
        capacity_label = tk.Label(frame, text =" Please select the capacity of your bag :")
        capacity_spinbox = tk.Spinbox(frame, from_=1, to=100 )
        capacity_label.grid(row=6, column=2)
        capacity_spinbox.grid(row=7,column=2)
        calculate_button =tk.Button(frame,text="Calculate", command = knapSack)
        calculate_button.grid(row=7,column=3)


def calculate(weights, values, capacity):
    result = knapSack(capacity, weights, values)
    # Create a label to display the result
    result_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Result: " + str(result))
    result_label.grid(row=14, column=0)

def print_value_table(table):
    print("Value Table:")
    for row in table:
        print(row)
        
def print_keep_table(table):
    print("Keep Table:")
    for row in table:
        print(row)
        
def knapSack(W, wt, val): 
    n=len(val)
    value_table = [[0 for x in range(W + 1)] for x in range(n + 1)]
    keep_table = [[0 for x in range (W+1)] for x in range (n+1)]
    for i in range(n + 1): 
        for j in range(W + 1): 
            if i == 0 or j == 0: 
                value_table[i][j] = 0
                keep_table[i][j] = 0
            elif wt[i-1] <= j: 
                if(val[i-1] + value_table[i-1][j-wt[i-1]]) > value_table[i-1][j]:
                    value_table[i][j] = val [i-1]+ value_table[i-1][j-wt[i-1]]
                    keep_table [i][j] = 1
                else:
                    value_table[i][j] = value_table[i-1][j]
                    keep_table[i][j] = 0
            else: 
                value_table[i][j] = value_table[i-1][j]
                keep_table[i][j] = 0
    print_value_table(value_table)
    print_keep_table(keep_table)
    return value_table[n][W]        



num_entries_label = tk.Label(frame, text="Enter the number of items:")
num_entries_label.grid(row=1, column=1)

num_entries_entry = tk.Entry(frame)
num_entries_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

next_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Next", command=on_submit)
next_button.grid(row=3, column=1)

title_label = tk.Label(frame, text = "Hi! Please follow the instructions!")
title_label.config(font=("Arial", 18))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], read: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic] and how to create a [mre]. Please provide the complete traceback.

Comment: What is 'W' do? knapSack(W,

Comment: 'W' is the knapsack capacity

Comment: You have `tk.Button(..., command=knapSack)`, therefore when the user clicks the button, `tkinter` calls `knapSack()` with no arguments but your function needs 3 arguments. That is why you get the error.